# MySQL: Search-Term should consider point and comma for float

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to improve my SQL-Search. The current query looks like this:

```
$query->where('(a.id LIKE ' . $search . ' OR a.invoiceid LIKE ' . 
$search . ' OR c.lastname LIKE ' . $search . ' OR c.firstname LIKE ' . 
$search .  ' OR c.company LIKE ' . $search . ' OR a.creationdate LIKE ' . 
$search . ' OR a.duedate LIKE ' . $search .  ' OR a.totalsum LIKE ' . 
$search . ')');
```

This already works great :-)

But it would be even better if I could type in `1,23` instead of `1.23` and get an result for the saved float (`totalsum`).

The date-fields are saved as `DATETIME`. It would be great to get results on using other date-formats in search like `22.09.1980` and get a hit for `1980-09-22 00:00:00` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Replace function for the comma:

```
'a.totalsum LIKE REPLACE(' . $search . ", ',', '.')"
```

But for the date the task is more complex as you'll need to recognize the pattern. There is a [library](https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_preg) for MySQL to support regular expressions replace. But I suggest you to use PHP:

```
//replace dd.mm.yyyy -> yyyy-mm-dd
$search = preg_replace('/^(\d{2})\.(\d{2})\.(\d{4})$/', '$3-$2-$1', $search);
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to do something like `a.totalsum LIKE ' . 
$search . ' OR a.totalsum LIKE SOMECONVERTINGMETHOD(`.$search.')'`?

Comment: @MyFault Let me see, maybe mysql has regexps

Comment: @MyFault I think I found one for the comma: `a.totalsum LIKE REPLACE(' . $search . ', \',\', \'.\')'`

Comment: Got something: `SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(creationdate, '%d.%m.%Y') LIKE "01.09.2015"`

should work, shouldn't it?

Comment: @MyFault I gave you a PHP suggestion to convert date pattern to MySQL format

Comment: @MyFault No, DATE_FORMAT won't work. This function converts from MYSQL -> custom format. And you need the opposite: from custom -> MySQL

Comment: Hm, but important is that search and field are matching. So it should not matter if I reformat the createdon-field or the input, or am I wrong?

Comment: @MyFault Yes, it's not the best solution, but you can save the result of `preg_replace` into a different variable and if it's not equal to original string create another `OR` and use it there. In this case it will be safe.